# 教師あり学習と教師なし学習の違いは何ですか？

Tags: アルゴリズム, 機械学習, 人工知能

何冊か本を読んだのですが、抽象的ではっきりした理解を得ることができませんでした。
具体的な例を教えていだだけますか

Answer (score 8, accepted):

概念的に言うと、

- **教師あり学習**: 人間等が付けたラベルによって、教えられた構造を学び取る
- **教師なし学習**: データから規則性を発見して学び取る

という違いになると思います。

---

もう少し具体的に、0から9までの数字1文字が書かれた画像が沢山あるとしましょう。

[image: 数字画像の例]

この画像一枚一枚に、0から9までのどの数字が書かれているのかという*ラベルを人間が付けて*、それを学習するのが教師あり学習です。
アルゴリズムが、人間の認識を真似るように学習が行われます。
学習が完了した暁には、新しい入力画像に対して、どの数字が書かれているのかを正しく判断できるようになります。

一方で教師なし学習の場合は、画像データがあるだけです。
学習アルゴリズムは、このデータだけをみてこのデータの性質を探ります。
すると、大体0から9までの10種類のパターンに大きく分けることができます。
このようにデータだけからその規則性を学び取るのが教師なし学習です。

[image: 0から9までの数字の特徴空間へのプロット]